# DOMDocument - createTextNode, encoding issue

Tags: vb6, domdocument, createtextnode

I have a problem with createTextNode method e special characters like '>', '<':

```
Dim xmlDoc As DOMDocument
Dim codeXML as String
Dim n As IXMLDOMNode

codeXML = '<data>value</data>'
Set n = xmlDoc.createTextNode(codeXML)
```

I need a result like this:

```
<main><data>value</data></main>
```

but I get

```
<main>&lt;data&gt;value&lt;/data&gt;</main>
```

How can I solve that problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is your intent to create the whole XML doc with literal xml like that?  If you are adding child nodes then you should create those nodes and add them to the root node.  But if the intent is to use string data holding the xml then the approach is different.

Comment: I have a string with an XML structure that I want to add as a child nodes in my XML doc. So as you can see all XML tags were encoded. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to create a second Document to serve as the XML parser for these XML literals.  You can use LoadXML to pass the string in and get validated XML objects.  You can then Import the node to the original/main DOM Document you are building.

Comment: Thank you very much... I've used LoadXML and then appendChild to my main DOM Document. Now it works!