# Avoid encoding in Document->createTextNode

Tags: xml, vb.net

```
Dim xmlDoc As DOMDocument
Dim codeXML as String
Dim n As IXMLDOMNode

codeXML = '<data>value</data>'
Set n = xmlDoc.createTextNode(codeXML)
```

I need a result like this:

```
<main><data>value</data></main>
```

but I get

```
<main>&lt;data&gt;value&lt;/data&gt;</main>
```

Please help in resolving this.

Thanks,

Comment: This isn't Java.  Furthermore, what is your question exactly?

Comment: Why is this tagged as Java. Isn't it VB ?

Answer (score 1):

You're creating `<data>value</data>` as a text node, but you don't want a text node. Instead you want an element `<data>` (created via `createElement`) with a nested text node of `value` (using the above).

To be clear, `<data>value</data>` consists of an XML element with a nested text node. If you call `createTextNode()` and pass in your XML then it'll encode it as text and create a text node. *You can't store this text without that entity encoding occurring*.

It helps to understand the different node subclasses in the DOM. Here's a [useful tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodes.asp) on this very topic.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Sorry about the VB syntax at the top, im trying to build an XML file in java and im facing similar problem.
Actually the found the answer here in some old post(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785564/domdocument-createtextnode-encoding-issue). 
But still not clear on what needs to be done.

I need to retain '<''>''&" etc.. symbols without it getting encoded when passed to Document.createTextNode(<data>value</data>).

Please let me know as how to resolve this.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply Brian.

The input data to createTextNode can be of any format like "<data>text<stackoverflow/>carreers<2.0></data>".I want to avoid encoding to the text. 

saw similar post in this community.
It was suggested to use loadXML using a new Dodument object and then append it to original Document object. I'm trying on this. Looking forward for help on this.

Answer (score 0):

As Brian suggested, try:

```
mainElement.createElement("data").setTextContent("value");
```

Comment: The codeXML is basically a String vlaue which takes XML form not exactly a proper XML.

It can also take value like
<data>text<stackoverflow/>carreers<2.0></data>

I dont want this tags to be encoded, It had to retained as the way they are.
Here in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785564/domdocument-createtextnode-encoding-issue

It's suggested to use loadXML using a new Codument object and then append it to original Document object. I'm trying on this.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,