# How to avoid encoding of <,>,& with Document.createTextNode

Tags: java, xml

```
class XMLencode 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    try{

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
    Element root = doc.createElement("roseindia");
       doc.appendChild(root);
    Text elmnt=doc.createTextNode("<data>sun</data><abcdefg/><end/>");
       root.appendChild(elmnt);
     TransformerFactory tranFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance(); 
    Transformer aTransformer = tranFactory.newTransformer(); 
    Source src = new DOMSource(doc); 
    Result dest = new StreamResult(System.out); 
    aTransformer.transform(src, dest); 

    }catch(Exception e){
     System.out.println(e.getMessage());
         }
     }
}
```

Here is my above piece of code.
The output generated is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><roseindia>&lt;data&gt;sun&lt;/data&gt;&lt;abcdefg/&gt;&lt;end/&gt;</roseindia>
```

I dont want the tags to be encoded. I need the output in this fashion.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><roseindia><data>sun</data><abcdefg/><end/></roseindia>
```

Please help me on this.

Thanks,
Mohan

Answer (score 8):

**Short Answer**

You could leverage the `CDATA` mechanism in XML to prevent characters from being escaped.  Below is an example of the DOM code:

```
doc.createCDATASection("<foo/>");
```

The content will be:

```
<![CDATA[<foo/>]]>
```

---

**LONG ANSWER**

Below is a complete example of leveraging a CDATA section using the DOM APIs.

```
package forum12525152;

import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = db.newDocument();

        Element rootElement = document.createElement("root");
        document.appendChild(rootElement);

        // Create Element with a Text Node
        Element fooElement = document.createElement("foo");
        fooElement.setTextContent("<foo/>");
        rootElement.appendChild(fooElement);

        // Create Element with a CDATA Section
        Element barElement = document.createElement("bar");
        CDATASection cdata = document.createCDATASection("<bar/>");
        barElement.appendChild(cdata);
        rootElement.appendChild(barElement);

        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
        t.transform(source, result);
    }

}
```

***Output***

Note the difference in the `foo` and `bar` elements even though they have similar content.  I have formatted the result of running the demo code to make it more readable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<root>
    <foo>&lt;foo/&gt;</foo>
    <bar><![CDATA[<bar/>]]></bar>
</root>
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of writing like this `doc.createTextNode("<data>sun</data><abcdefg/><end/>");`

You should create each element.

```
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
class XMLencode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
            Element root = doc.createElement("roseindia");
            doc.appendChild(root);

            Element data = doc.createElement("data");
            root.appendChild(data);
            Text elemnt = doc.createTextNode("sun");
            data.appendChild(elemnt);
            Element data1 = doc.createElement("abcdefg");
            root.appendChild(data1);

            //Text elmnt = doc.createTextNode("<data>sun</data><abcdefg/><end/>");
            //root.appendChild(elmnt);

            TransformerFactory tranFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer aTransformer = tranFactory.newTransformer();
            Source src = new DOMSource(doc);
            Result dest = new StreamResult(System.out);
            aTransformer.transform(src, dest);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,but the xml data we are getting is dynamic and hence we cant build each element individually and append to root element.please suggest any alternative approaches...thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the doc.createTextNode and use a workaround (long) for the escaped characters.

```
SOAPMessage msg = messageContext.getMessage();

header.setTextContent(seched);
```

Then use

```
Source src = msg.getSOAPPart().getContent();
```

To get the content, the transform it to string

```
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.  setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
StreamResult result1 = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
transformer.transform(src, result1);
```

Replace the string special characters

```
String xmlString = result1.getWriter().toString()
.replaceAll("&lt;", "<").
replaceAll("&gt;", ">");
System.out.print(xmlString);
```

the oposite  string to dom with the fixed escaped characters

```
DocumentBuilder db =  DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource is = new InputSource();
is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlString));
Document doc = db.parse(is);
Source src123 = new DOMSource(doc);
```

Then set it back to the soap message
`msg.getSOAPPart().setContent(src123);`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `createTextNode` - the whole point of it is to insert some text (as data) into the document, not a fragment of raw XML.

Use a combination of `createTextNode` for the text and `createElement` for the elements.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,but the xml data we are getting is dynamic and hence we cant build each element individually and append to root element.please suggest any alternative approaches...thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I dont want the tags to be encoded. I need the output in this fashion.

Then you *don't* want a text node at all - which is why `createTextNode` isn't working for you. (Or rather, it's working fine - it's just not doing what you want). You should probably just parse your XML string, then import the document node from the result into your new document.

Of course, if you know the elements beforehand, don't express them as text in the first place - use a mixture of `createElement`, `createAttribute`, `createTextNode` and `appendChild` to create the structure.

It's entirely possible that something like [JDOM](http://jdom.org/) will make this simpler, but that's the basic approach.

Comment: @user1686082: I think you have to parse the dynamic xml string as a DOM and append the DOM to the root. Is that you want to do?

Comment: @user1686082: I've already given you the alternative: you parse the the XML as a document, and import the nodes into your new document. (Copying and pasting the same comment as a reply to every answer gives the distinct impression that you haven't really read the answers thoroughly, btw...)

Comment: @Roy Ling - I have xml data as a string. How can i parse this string as a DOM? 

Sorry i'm new to this. Please help in finding the solution.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - Sorry, I dont have prior experience working on building dynamic XML's. 

Looking out for an alternative if i can't use createTextNode().

Comment: @user1686082: you may refer to JAXP tutorial - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/intro/dom.html

Comment: @user1686082: Did you try researching how you parse XML from a string to a Document? It's very important that you learn how to find things out for yourself, only relying on the community when you get stuck.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Here the input to text not an xml(it;s a string which has XML kind of data)Since it's not an XML i can't parse it as  suggested.

What im looking for is to avoid encoding for the data passed as arguement to createTextNode(). 
It's been quite a long time since im trying to sort this out or find an alternate solution for this! 

Please see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785564/domdocument-createtextnode-encoding-issue and suggest me what the reply actually meant. The solution suggested their might have worked, but im not clear on what needs to be done.

Comment: @user1686082: XML "kind of data" is far too vague. Either it's XML and you want to keep that XML structure, or it's not. For example, suppose the text is actually: `<foo><bar></foo></bar>` that's invalid as XML, and *couldn't* be maintained directly. You need to be *much* clearer in your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Mohan,

You can't use Document.createTextNode(). That methos transforms (or escapes) the charactes in your XML.
Instead, you need to build two separate Documents from the 2 XML's and use *importNode*.

I use Document.importNode() like this to solve my problem:

Build your builders:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document oldDoc = builder.parse(isOrigXml); //this is XML as InputSource
Document newDoc = builder.parse(isInsertXml); //this is XML as InputSource
```

Next, build a NodeList of the Element/Node you want to import. Create a Node from the NodeList. Create another Node of what you are going to import using importNode. Build the last Node of the final XML as such:

```
NodeList nl = newDoc.getElementByTagName("roseindia"); //or whatever the element name is
Node xmlToInsert = nl.item(0);
Node importNode = oldDoc.importNode(xmlToImport, true);
Node target = ((NodeList) oldDoc.getElementsByTagName("ELEMENT_NAME_OF_LOCATION")).item(0);
target.appendChild(importNode);

Source source = new DOMSource(target);
....
```

The rest is standard Transformer - StringWriter to StreamResult stuff to get the results.